# java dom search xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

hello i have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new2.xsl"?>
<patients>
    <patient>
    <stoixeia_astheni>
        <arithmos_eksetasis>1</arithmos_eksetasis>
        <imerominia_eksetasis>11/12/2005</imerominia_eksetasis>
        <amka>14385</amka>

    </stoixeia_astheni>
    <stoixeia_epikoinonias>
        <dieuthinsi>Μητσοπούλου 20</dieuthinsi>

    </stoixeia_epikoinonias>
    <loipa_stoixeia>
        <fylo>Aρρεν</fylo>

    </loipa_stoixeia>
    </patient>
    <patient>
    same code here
    </patient>

</patients>
```

and i want to search this by amka value.
i have tried this:

```
 Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
            NodeList root= doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
            for(int i=0; i<root.getLength(); i++){
                if(root.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(2).getNodeValue()=="14385"){
                    pw.println("Gataki<br>");
                }
            }
```

but runtime error occurs

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare strings. Also learning XPaths might help you here.

Comment: @Zutty You are right, but this is not the only mistake

Comment: take a look at this xpath tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this xpath

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(<uri_as_string>);
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/patients/patient/stoixeia_astheni/amka/text()");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Just in case takke a look at this xpath syntaxis

```
/   Selects from the root node
//  Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are
.   Selects the current node
..  Selects the parent of the current node
@   Selects attributes
```

Comment: I did a little modification in the xpath to let you get directly the node value. As per the imports i think this is something you can do by yourself. You can print the lists of nodes like this `for(int i =0;i<nl.getLength();i++) {
   Node n = nl.item(i);
   System.out.println(n.getNodeValue());
  }`